# saving multiple check-boxes as different records in php

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

Am trying to save the result of multiple check-boxes as separate records. my code is not functioning. please help!

```
<?php

session_start();
$id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=idp;charset=utf8','root', '');

foreach($_POST['comp'] as $val){
    $tmp['user_id'] = $id;
    $tmp['comp_id'] = $val;
    $vars[] = $tmp;
}

$qry = "INSERT INTO compentency_result (user_id, result) VALUES (:user_id, :comp_id)";

try
{
    $sql = $db->prepare($qry);
    $numRows = 0;
    foreach($vars as $insert){
        $numRows += $sql->execute($insert);
    }
    print("<p>There were {$numRows} inserted into the database!</p>");
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    print("<p>Oops! There was an issue - this is the message: {$e->getMessage()}</p>");
}

?>
```

The result is showing me that nothing is added to the database.

Comment: you're not binding anything.

Comment: *I quit wearing things that are binding Ralph.*, but you should always bind your query values, right @Fred-ii-

Comment: *Right you are Sam* - @JayBlanchard

Comment: The way you're collecting the number of rows affected is a little weird as you're expecting a 'true' to return a '1'. The behavior here might not be that consistent.

Comment: please, how would you suggest i fix this? very new to PDO.. thanks

Comment: someone called me out here and deleted their comment, *why?* - something about seeing example #3 on PDO binding on http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php

Comment: @anelka Have you tried Jay's answer below? if that still doesn't work, you will need to edit your question and post the HTML form where you have the checkboxes. There may be a few contributing reasons, one of which being that you're not treating the checkboxes as an array.

Answer (score 2):

To bind the parameters individually you would do this:

```
try
{
    $sql = $db->prepare($qry);
    $numRows = 0;
    foreach($vars as $insert){
        $sql->bindParam(':user_id', $insert['user_id'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $sql->bindParam(':comp_id', $insert['comp_id'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $sql->execute();
        $numRows += $sql->rowCount(); // get the rows affected this way
    }
    echo "<p>There were {$numRows} inserted into the database!</p>";
}
```

In addition, I added a more proper and reliable method of getting the affected rows, using [`rowCount()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php).

If you don't want to bind the elements individually you can use `execute()` with an array as shown in [Demystifying PDO](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html)

Comment: please, check the code i inserted below. it's not saving into the DB

Comment: You need to add some error checking to your code @anelka. You have no idea if your queries or connection is working.